# Sending SAML request to NetSuite

Tags: saml, netsuite

I've been navigating and toying with features of netsuite, for one feature that came across was the SAML single sign-on. I can not understand how it works or even get it working.

I've read the numerous SAML documents on suiteanswers however, they leave me puzzled.

Does anyone have a working netsuite SAML code example or documentation?

A hurl.it would suffice also!

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a specific SAML snippet, but IIRC SSO needs to be enabled/provisioned.  Kindly navigate to Setup, Company, View Billing Information.  There must be users provisioned towards the bottom under: Two Factor Authentication Users (Should show Provisioned Quantity and Used Quantity.)  I believe there is also a place on Role Permissions where a Role can be defined as single Sign On ONLY - but I don't think that is what you are asking.

Like I said, I have no snippet, however on the Suite-Answers Site, They give me a reference Link that has a PDF that shows a sample for you.  The PDF Itself is Located here: https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=7490306&c=NLCORP&h=cd5c1c4877483ebab26b&_xt=.pdf

I've made an offline http nonsecured version here stored in Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohiu6f308szu6rd/SAML_Setup_ADFS_Netsuite.pdf